# Using RecyclerView with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I built the RecycleView widget with CardView from this tutorial:

[Android L Tutorials (Part 3) - RecyclerView and CardView](http://www.treyrobinson.net/blog/android-l-tutorials-part-3-recyclerview-and-cardview/)

Now Im trying to show it as a Fragment.

Here is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment {  
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CountryAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    public FragmentActivity(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(CountryManager.getInstance().getCountries(), R.layout.card_layout, getActivity());
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

MainActivity where I call my fragment:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentActivity fragment = new FragmentActivity();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_list, fragment).commit();
}
```

Here is my activity_main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".CountryActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".CountryActivity"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My card_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/countryImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:tint="@color/photo_tint"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/countryName"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:textSize="24sp"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and frame_layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/container_list">

</FrameLayout>
```

The app crashes when it calls the fragment.
Your help will be appreciated guys.

Comment: You should describe what the problem is. What is the unexpected behavior that you are facing?

Comment: the app crashes when calling the fragment

Comment: why are u using name "FragmentActivity"   change it first because its already base class.    thats why getFragmentManager()  gives nothing.

Comment: @kinsell can you provide the logs you get when the application crashes ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class DemoActivity extends Fragment {  
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CountryAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    public DemoActivity(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(CountryManager.getInstance().getCountries(), R.layout.card_layout, getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Please use this code hope so it will be help you.

Comment: Explain why this works when you post answers, otherwise it's not as useful.

Comment: @David you have set Adapter before making Adapter object that time its get null object of adapter that is reason of crash your app.

Answer (score 2):

You are inflating the wrong layout in your `Fragment` class

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, container, false);  //Here you are inflating the row layout instad of the fragment
```

Just change the layout reference for the proper one

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_main, container, false);
```

Also in your MainActivity change the layout resource to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.frame_layout);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Carlos I fixed that, but the app is still crashing

Comment: Whats's the exception you are getting?

Comment: E/FragmentManager﹕ No view found for id 0x7f080042 (com.empire.test01:id/container_list) for fragment FragmentActivity{23833986 #0 id=0x7f080042} @Carlos J This is what I get

Comment: Well I dont have enough reputation points, when i do, Ill make sure you get you get your points @Carlos J

Comment: Didi you change the layout in your MainActivity as well??

Comment: its showing the fragment but its giving an exception : No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: I need more than that, can you post the full logcat output?